# Excel using a range of cells to return value corresponding to an adjacent cell in the correct cell

Tags: excel

I have been trying this for days, and can't get it correct.

I want to see if any value in column A matches any value in column C, and if so, return the value from column B into column D, BESIDE the match in column C.

I have tried all the suggestions for If, IFERROR, MATCH, VLOOKUP, etc, but can't get it to work.  Any help would be most welcome!!

[Here is a picture of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJYgn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper column:

1. In column D, use `COUNTIF` on each row to check the number of times that a cell in column A appears. `=COUNTIF(C:C,A1)`.
2. In column E, use the formula `=IF(D1>0, B1,"")` and copy down

(you could of course combine these if you don't want to use the extra column)

Answer (score 0):

In coumn `D` use formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C:C,A:B,2,0),"")
```

Note: this formula uses **Implicit Intersection** [see here for some info](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-14-handling-whole-columns-using-implicit-intersection/)

Comment: Thanks!  That MOSTLY worked, but some cells have #N/A when they should have returned the value.  Others worked perfectly.

Comment: It will return `#N/A` if value in C is not found in A. What value _should_ it have returned?  Updated to return blank if not found

Comment: @smei Also you have some duplicates in `A` Formula returns first instance. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the info, Chris.  Yes, I see that there are duplicates in col A - I would then need the sum of all B values for each instance in col A that matches a value in col C.

Comment: I don't know how to paste a screenshot of the results here, but D1 returned #N/A when it should have returned 35,334.60.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're starting in Row 1, in column D use:

`=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$C1)>0,B1,"NO MATCH")`

Drag that down as far as you need. This formula is saying: if the value in C1 matches anything in column A, then return the value from B1.

If this isn't what you mean, then please be clearer. Your data example is unreadable. Post a screenshot, or at least type it so it is in columns and rows. It's also unclear what you mean by "BESIDE the match in column C" What value is matching which value? That is, if A1 matches any value in C, do you want the value of B1 to show up in D1? Or do you want the value of B5 to show up in D5, if A1 matched C5?

Comment: Thanks!! If A9 matches C2, I would like the value in B9 to populate D2.  I tried your formula and it returns B2 in D2, rather than B9.

Comment: I see you said above that there are duplicates in column A. Are there also Duplicates in column C?